# Other third party controls

Tags: asp.net, windows, user-interface, web

I am using **farpoint** third party control for current application **vc++** and **Vb6**.

I wanted to migrate the projects asp.net windows as well as web application.
But, farpoint product is costly now, so I want to move to another third party control.

I don't know about third party controls, so, please can anybody give me an idea for which one I can use instead of farpoint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is many third party controls for .net but you have to purchase to use the library for business.you can use free trail if you want to use as developer.

you can read this [post](http://www.infoq.com/research/dotnet-web-components) and choose the best third party for you.